# Is there a bug calculating the "change" field value for new users in the "User Leagues"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users, user-accounts, user-rank

I found the "User Leagues" for the first time and decided to check my score for the year.  I was surprised to see that my rank had apparently decreased by 10242 year-over-year.
(I used to be 30th?? - awesome!)

[image: change: -10242]

I've only been a member for 16 days, and this looked a little strange, so I thought I'd read about the User Leagues rankings on Meta Stack Overflow. When I linked through to the User Leagues a 2nd time (in another tab), I found that my rank now showed and wihh an increase of 18616.

[image: change: +18616]

Has anyone else seen this?  Is this a bug or is this common for newer users, and I missed the explanation elsewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be better now.  The green "+18616" number is the correct one: if you don't have previous rank, we rank you dead last, so the first week/month/etc you appear you jump way up.

There was some strange inconsistency between the webservers, which is why the correct number showed up only some of the time.

**Edit**

On further thought, "+18616" is still a bit confusing, so we'll just show "not previously ranked" for those users.

Comment: Yes, I got all sorts of different results when I checked yearly & quarterly rankings.  But as of this morning... it looks to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you’ve been a member for only 16 days, there is no data for you for last year. Therefore it’s probably a bug arising from bad error handling: the programmer failed to take this situation into account, so the number displayed is garbage.

Comment: Yeah, exactly - thanks. I was seeing the same thing when I checked quarterly rankings as well (no history == funny results).  Just wondering if this was a known bug.